# What's the difference between `answeredInRound` and `roundId` in a chainlink price feed?

Tags: chainlink

In a chainlink price feed, we can get data by calling:

```js
function latestRoundData() external view
    returns (
        uint80 roundId,
        int256 answer,
        uint256 startedAt,
        uint256 updatedAt,
        uint80 answeredInRound
    )
```

With the following return values:

- `roundId`: The round ID
- `answer`: The answer for this round
- `startedAt`: Timestamp of when the round started
- `updatedAt`: Timestamp of when the round was updated
- `answeredInRound`: The round ID in which the answer was computed

Would `roundId` ever be different from `answeredInRound`? What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`roundId` is the "round" the answer was created in. Every time a Chainlink network updates a price feed, they add 1 to the round.

`answeredInRound` is a legacy variable from when the Chainlink price feeds was on the Flux Aggregator model instead of OCR (Off-Chain Reporting) and it was possible for a price to be updated slowly and leek into the next "round". This is now no longer the case.